# How to create a pivot table with filters in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am basically trying to automate the work that I normally do in Excel, which is data cleaning and analysis. I've got the data cleaning part down but I'm having trouble with the analysis/summary part through python. I basically just want a count of all the variables in a column, and then filter those counts based on another column. I'm basically trying to duplicate what I do with a pivot table:

[Pivot table summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8QY7.png)

I've tried to automate this with python:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('Appointments booked Q4 2021.csv')
OneOnOne = 'Final', 'Follow Up', 'Initial', 'Injection'

#Table of provider count only for final, follow, initial, and injection appointments
df3 = df[df['Appointment Type'].isin(OneOnOne)]
df3 = df3.groupby('Provider Type').size()

print(df3)

df3.to_csv('test_dataclean3.csv', index=False)
```

It outputs what I want in the terminal:

```
Provider Type
Community Health Navigation     247
Dietitian                       685
Kinesiology                     294
MH Navigation                  1718
MH Therapist                   1338
Nursing                        1601
Pharmacist                      133
Specialist                      749
```

This is fine and all but when I write it to an excel file all it gives me is the column with the counts, without a total row at the bottom and without the row labels of 'Provider Types':

[df3 output without row labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sALxq.png)

Is there a way to output it to an excel file exactly how it displays in a pivot table but with python? Because I will also need this output this way to match the row labels and do calculations with a similar database, so I can calculate the difference between the two.

This is my first post so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `df3 = df3.groupby('Provider Type', as_index=False).size()`. Or save with index `df3.to_csv('test_dataclean3.csv')`

Comment: @QuangHoang when I include index=False in the groupby function, it gives me an error.

Comment: Then use `df3 = df3.groupby('Provider Type').size().reset_index(name='count')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang you bastard, you did it!! Thank you, the last part would be how I can get a total column row at the bottom?

Comment: `df3.loc['total'] = df3.sum()` before save.

Comment: @QuangHoang it's totalling the 'count' column which is what I want, but then it ends up concatenating all the row labels above it instead of having a 'Total' row label: "Community Health NavigationDietitianKinesiologyMH NavigationMH TherapistNursingPharmacistSpecialist 6765"